# Given that (a-1/a)=3 determine the value of (a+1/a)^2 without solving for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please excuse my noobery but I'm *very* new to high school maths for reasons unimportant.

I'm using [this](https://www.siyavula.com/read/maths/grade-10/01-algebraic-expressions-05#toc-id-15) site as my study guide to get through high school math and the questions (close to the bottom of the page) that I'm having trouble with go like this:

> 1. Answer the following:
>
> (a)  Expand: $(a+\frac{1}{a})^2$.
>
> (b) Given that $(a+\frac{1}{a})=3$, determine the value of $(a+\frac{1}{a})^2$ without solving for $x$.
>
> (c) Given that $(a-\frac{1}{a})=3$, determine the value of $(a+\frac{1}{a})^2$ without solving for $x$.

I can do (a) and (b) but I get stuck at (c) even though the website gives the answers but their explanation doesn't make any sense  and I think the problem is that the site doesn't explain how to do these sorts of problems, what these problems are about, where to go find out what all this is, etc. so I'm hoping someone can please explain to me how to do this step for step so that my puny mind can understand it too.

**Edit:** If you'd like me to post the answers according to the website, please let me know, I only exclude them because of how much space that would take.

Comment: $$\left(a+\dfrac1a\right)^2=?$$ and $$\left(a-\dfrac1a\right)^2=?$$

Comment: for $(b) $ it is simply 9.

Comment: Oh right, I actually got that one too, lemme quickly update.

Comment: Where is the variable $x$ used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**
just observe that

$$(a+1/a)^2=(a-1/a)^2+4$$
because

$$(a+1/a)^2=$$
$$a^2+1/a^2+2.a.(1/a)=$$
$$a^2+1/a^2+2$$
and
$$(a-1/a)^2=$$
$$a^2+1/a^2-2.a. (1/a) =$$
$$a^2+1/a^2-2=$$
$$a^2+1/a^2+2 -4$$

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris It is obvious that we can make mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but how do we know that adding 4 will change the plus sign to a minus? So for example why couldn't I add 8 or subtract 2 or multiply by 432, etc. to get change the positive to a negative?

Answer (score 1):

(b) If $\displaystyle a+\frac1a=3$, then $\displaystyle\left(a+\frac1a\right)^2=3^2=9$.

(c) If $\displaystyle a-\frac1a=3$ then $\displaystyle\left(a-\frac1a\right)^2=9$. But $\displaystyle\left(a-\frac1a\right)^2=a^2-2+\frac1{a^2}$ and so $\displaystyle\left(a+\frac1a\right)^2=a^2+2+\frac1{a^2}=\left(a^2-2+\frac1{a^2}\right)+4=13.$

Answer (score 0):

For (a) you have to use this:

$(x+y)^2= x^2+y^2 +2xy$

For (b) if you have:

$x=3$ then $x^2 = 3^2$. If you substitute $x$ with the value $(a+1/a)$ then $9=3^2=x^2=(a+1/a)^2$

For (c) you can use the hint given by Salahamam_Fatima and the (b) section, now for $x=(a-1/a)$. Can you solve this now?